# Hard drive failing or problem with file system?

Tags: hard-drive

My system goes into read-mode frequently and want me to do fsck manually  when boot up. So, i want to know whether my hard drive is corrupted or just an issue with file system.

P.S: My system goes into read-mode so can't do something with smarttools etc.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: You should give more details (OS version, result of fsck, ...)  As such, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: yes its a dual boot. @heynnema

Comment: Please see my answer, including the update #1. Perform. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk's SMART data...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start the `Disks` application
- select the disk in the left pane
- click the "hamburger" icon
- select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the data
- run the tests

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

**In Windows... because you dual-boot...**

- boot into Windows
- **important: if you've installed any drivers that allow you to access Ubuntu partitions, uninstall it now!**
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: